# Cypress click button using enter keyword

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am testing my application and I'm trying to invoke button click with enter keyword:

```
<v-btn
    class="submit-button"
    block
    color="primary"
    @click="login"
  >
    Log In
</v-btn>

cy.get('.submit-button').type('{enter}');
```

Is there any alternative way, to click button on enter key press?

I'm using vuetify framework and `v-btn` component.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `cy.get('.submit-button').type('{enter}', {force: true});`, assuming the locator that you're using is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, this reproduces the same error. I've updated my question with HTML tag that I'm using.

Comment: Hi. As the error says the `type` command requires a typeable (input/textarea) element in order to work. Your code yields a button element type, that's why it fails. In case you have any input/textarea element on your page, you have to `cy.get('input').type('{enter}')`

Comment: @AlexIzbas look at the message - button is a typeable element.

Answer (score 1):

Vue translates

```html
<v-btn class="submit-button">Log In</v-btn>
```

into

```html
<button class="submit-button">
  <span class="v-btn__content">Log In</span>
</button>
```

Logically this test

```js
cy.get('.submit-button').type('{enter}');
```

should work since you are selecting the `button` element by it's class, but somehow the focus is getting messed up.

The fix is to insert a `.focus()` before the `.type()` command.

```js
cy.get('.submit-button').focus().type('{enter}');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow, second case with selecting parent element is being visible and found by cypress, but once I try to type('{enter}') it reproduces the same error as before. Somehow it keeps typing enter into span instead of button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit the whole form. See here - [Cypress submit docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/submit.html#Usage). It manipulates the submmiting with enter.

Comment: Button is not part of the form scope. So I'm not able to achieve submitting within the form. But thanks for the participating in the discussion